# Junit: less-than assertion?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

Is there anything like `assertThat(a, lessThan(b));` ? I'm currently using Junit 4.8.1 and I haven't been able to find lessThan. Instead I have to do `assertTrue(a < b)`, but this has a drawback that it doesn't print two numbers in test log.

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  But you could easily write your own that provides a useful message...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried JUnit + [Hamcrest](https://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/)? See this blog post  for some examples—it looks almost exactly like what you posted:

[JUnit 4 Showcase – assertThat and Hamcrest Matchers](http://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/junit-4-showcase-assertthat-and-hamcrest-matchers/)

Alternatively, there's also [ComparableAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/ComparableAssert.html) from the [JUnit-addons project](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I checked Hamcrest, and there was nothing like the lessThan function

Comment: It's in the docs: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/number/OrderingComparison.html#lessThan(T)

Comment: Or, if you go through `Matchers` to see everything that's available, as [`Matchers.lessThan`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#lessThan%28T%29).

Comment: the `Matchers` class doesn't seem to come with the *Hamcrest* that *Junit* uses. Adding **Hamcrest-library**, as an additional dependency, got the me the necessary `Matchers` class.

Answer (score 4):

You can import Hamcrest like this and use the Matchers.lessThan() method.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

assertThat(foo, Matchers.lessThan(bar));
```